# The ever increasing pull of a black hole

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, acceleration

If something is caught in the pull of a black hole and keeps accelerating it can't keep accelerating with no limits or else it would accelerate beyond c. So is there a limit on how fast acceleration can increase for an object being pulled in by a black hole? (forgive me if this a horrible question or too broad or off-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit in acceleration, but since acceleration is the rate of change of velocity per time, and the time dilatation of the falling particle relative to an outer observer goes to infinity at the event horizon (where the escape velocity would be the speed of light), the falling object never makes it through that border from the viewpoint of an outer observer, because everything freezes at the horizon. From the perspective of the falling particle everything is normal since it is just falling freely and doesn't feel the time dilatation it suffers. For a simple relativistic explanation see [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Interacting_with_an_event_horizon), for further details on the quantum perspective I recommend [Link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8bhtEgB8Mo) and [Link 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMRYZMv0jRE)

Comment: 'from the point of view of the falling object everything is normal since it is just falling and accelerating freely and doesn't feel the time dilation it 'suffers'. If it is still accelerating and 'feels' no time dilation there is no limit to this acceleration. Is this correct?

Comment: Does a gravitational pull accelerate an object with sufficient mass?